# C++ - How can I implement multiple function of a template class without defining the template multiple times?

Tags: c++, templates

I wonder whether it is possible to implement multiple function of a template class without defining the template multiple times.

Declaration:

```
template <class T>
class Test{
    private:
    T field;
    public:
    Test(T value);
    T& get();
    void set(T value);
};
```

Implementation:

```
template <class T> Test<T>::Test(T value){ set(value); }
template <class T> T& Test<T>::get(){ return field; }
template <class T> void Test<T>::set(T value){ field = value; }
```

Copying `template <class T>` multiple times is somewhat error-prone. I wonder whether I can do something like this:

```
template <class T>{
Test<T>::Test(T value){ set(value); }
T& Test<T>::get(){ return field; }
void Test<T>::set(T value){ field = value; }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly implement those methods in the class definition.

Moreover, you don't need to separate the declaration and implementation of the template class . It has no side effect to the compilation. Because the implementation is not the real implementation. A template class is not a class, it's only a template that can be used to create a class. When you instantiate such a template class, e.g. **YourTemplate**, the compiler creates that new class. In order to create it, it has to see all the templated member functions (so that it can use the templates to create actual member functions such as **YourTemplate::function1()** ), and therefore these templated member functions must be in the header file, along with the template class body.

Comment: It is bad practice to put the definition in the declaration as it makes your code less readable.

Comment: If the functions are all one-liners, it might actually make the code *more* readable by removing the repetitions (like the OP wants to).

Comment: If not all the functions are one-liners, it would be better to separate declaration and implementation.

Comment: BTW, this guy is right. I have done a test with two piece of code. One have declaration and implementation merged, and the other have them separated. The generated ASM code are identical.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't separate it from the class you don't have to specify `template<class T>` every time.

Comment: Actually, I know this already. However, it seems that merging declaration and implementation is a bad practice. Anyway, I give you a +1 .

Comment: @KonfleDolex if you think it has disadvantages, it is up to you to consider the disadvantages against the advantage of not repeating template <class T>.

Comment: @KonfleDolex I usually do it if it's header only. Which is usually the case with templated classes anyway.

Comment: @KonfleDolex it is a good practice for your case. because your implementation can be inlined which increases the performance.

Comment: @Arpit it should make no difference for inlining in any decent compiler.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes in that case it can't be considered as bad practice .?

Comment: It is bad practice to put the definition in the declaration as it makes your code less readable.